# ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: usci_handle_connector_change: GET_CONNECTOR_STATUS failed (-110)

Tags: boot, 20.04, dell, fsck

On boot the following message appears and I cannot login (well I can but only if I go to tty3 and login via cli):
ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: usci_handle_connector_change: GET_CONNECTOR_STATUS failed (-110)

[Tech specs of my laptop, it's a Dell Latitude 5420](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXsOp.png)

I've tried to use fsck on recovery mode but [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcpkO.jpg) happens.

When I check some logs I can see some errors in nvme0n1. I have nvme0n1p1,
nvme0n1p2 and nvme0n1p3 (this one is encrypted). It seems that nvme0n1 is the entire disk, but i can't run fsck on it because it's always mounted.

Does anyone know what is this error?

Comment: Im having this same problem, would love some feedback

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is due to missing nvidia drivers.

First, hit Ctrl+Alt+F2 to open a terminal session.

Then, type `ubuntu-drivers devices`.  Your output might look like:

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001F95sv00001028sd0000097Dbc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile]
driver   : nvidia-driver-440 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Then, install all of the listed drivers, i.e.:

`sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440`

Then, reboot and it should boot smoothly.

Comment: But I'm using Intel, not nvidia

Mesa Intel® Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)
with lspci command --> 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a49 (rev 01)

Answer (score 0):

I had exact same issue and after hours of googling I resolved it.
When this error occurs press `ctrl + alt + F1`.
Login there if required, this will open terminal.
Now enter the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall --fix-missing ubuntu-desktop
```