# Getting an error or just a black screen when trying to dual-boot Ubuntu 20.04 on Dell XPS15 9520

Tags: dual-boot, apt, nvidia

I just installed Ubuntu on my laptop and I am trying to dual-boot Windows 11 and Ubuntu 20.04, however when trying to boot up Ubuntu, I get a black screen. When booting, sometimes the screen stays black and sometimes it gives me a message after several minutes. The message is:

```
[ 68.644489] ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: ucsi_handle_connector_change: GET_CONNECTOR_STATUS failed (-110)
```

I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370002/ucsi-acpi-usbc00000-usci-handle-connector-change-get-connector-status-failed) post and tried running the commands from both answers. Running the command from the first answer gives me "Reinstallation of ubuntu-desktop is not possible, it cannot be downloaded." If I try following the advice from the second answer, I get a bunch of failed to fetch errors and at the bottom it says "Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing" but running with `--fix-missing` doesn't work either and trying `sudo apt-get update` gives me a bunch of failed to fetch warnings and says "Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead."

I've been googling for hours and have no idea what's going on. It seems like the issue has to do with nvidia drivers, but I can't seem to find a fix that works. Everytime I try something, I run into more issues. I'm new to linux and only ever installed it on a virtual machine, so forgive me if I'm making some dumb mistakes.

[Laptop Specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyfzl.png)

Comment: You're probably giving too much importance to a message that is unlikely to be related with the graphical issue. Please [edit] the question and add full hardware specifications, to start with something.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Just added the specs at the bottom of the post

Comment: So, as expected, abrand new Nvidia card. (1) Have you selected the option to install 3rd party drivers during the Ubuntu installation? If you did then probably at some point you were asked to provide a password for MOKutil, did you?

Comment: Yes, I selected the option to install 3rd party drivers, but I don't remember being asked to provide a password for MOKutil.

Comment: Try booting Ubuntu as usual until it reaches the black screen. Press CTRL+ALT+F3, this hopefully will get you a TTY (command line), input your username then your password. Follow the instructions from here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot#How_can_I_do_non-automated_signing_of_drivers.3F . Before Windows 11 we'd simply disable Secure Boot and problem solved but W11 requires it. You can also disable it, boot Ubuntu graphically and follow the same instructions then reboot and re-enable Secure Boot.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to get things working now!